# How to split two mapped columns in a dataframe simultaneously in spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of this form

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|hashMap                               |name                         |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|[{"A":"0","B":"0","C":"0"}, {"X":"0"}]|[M, D]                       |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to split it to this

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|hashMap                               |name                         |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|"A":"0","B":"0","C":"0"               | M                           |
|"X":"0"                               | D                           |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I know explode split, but I don't know if it will work on two columns.
Also, its possible that sometimes there is only one value in both the columns

for example

```
+-----------+-----------+
|hashMap    |name       |
+-----------+-----------+
|[{"A":"0"} |[M]        |
+-----------+-----------+
```

How do make the explode split generic to handle this in scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the arrays and explode them using `inline`:

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr("inline(arrays_zip(hashMap, name))")
```